# Como inserir values dentro de um select ao inseri-lo no banco

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, magento

Preciso inserir dados no banco, estou pegando os dados de um banco antigo, eu tinha alguns atributos que tem um certo value, eu criei esses atributos no site para que eu possa receber os dados sem problema algum, os atributos que são do tipo select tem seus values, do site antigo por ter criado e deletado atributos os que são usados hoje em dia tem values "alto", como por exemplo 42, e esse mesmo atributo que crio no site novo vem com value 1, pelo fato de não ter sido deletado e inserido novamente, eu gostaria de saber como eu faria uma verificação para trocar os valores dos atributos que eu tenho.

**Exemplo de como adiciono os campos**

Como podem ver no código eu adiciono os campos assim, eu dou um select e depois coloco ele em seu devido lugar com `->setNomedoCampo($dadoselecionado)` no caso da `->setStoreId($loja)` vem setado como id 1 ou 2, por ter 2 lojas, mas antigamente aviam 4, então eu pego como 3 e 4 os valores do banco antigo, mas não existem esses valores no banco atual, apenas 1 e 2, como eu implantaria nesse código um "conversor" para que possa trocar esses valores?

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
                        $teste = array(
                                $clientes_id = $row['clientes_id'],
                                $nome = $row['nome'],
                                $sobrenome = $row['sobrenome'],
                                $site = $row['site'],
                                $loja = $row['loja'],
                                $grupo = $row['grupo'],
                                $prefixo = $row['prefixo'],
                                $assinatura = $row['assinatura']);

$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
                                $customer->setId($clientes_id)
                                         ->setFirstname($nome)
                                         ->setLastname($sobrenome)
                                         ->setWebsiteId($site)
                                         ->setStoreId($loja)
                                         ->setGroupId($grupo)
                                         ->setPrefix($prefixo)
                                         ->setMiddlename($assinatura);
```

**Segunda pergunta**

Eu gostaria de saber se tem como eu inserir um value no atributo sem que ele ganhe um value "padrão", tipo eu setar antes de colocar no banco um value para que possa bater com os values antigos. Embaixo podem ver como eu adiciono esses atributos novos no banco.

**Atributos**

Dentro de `"option" => array(...` é onde eu coloco as opções que serão selecionadas, teria como eu colocar um value para elas na hora da inserção aqui? Porque se tiver não teria a necessidade de fazer um conversor como no caso que expliquei acima.

```
    $installer->addAttribute("customer", "occupation",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Profissão",
    "input"    => "select",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "source" => "eav/entity_attribute_source_table",
    "option" => array('values' => array('System Analist', 'Administrator')) 
    ));
```

**Imagem com os values dos atributos que gostaria de alterar**

Então ali está os values atribuidos as options, 29, 30, 31, 32. Porém no outro site tem outros valores, logo quando eu for inserir no banco não será puxado esses valores de forma correta, alguém saberia se tem como setar esses valores antes de inserir?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui adicionar já setando um value numerico, tive que fazer a alteração dos valores "na mão". na parte do código onde está o if é onde eu faço a troca de valores, ao puxar esse valor na tabela pela sua linha $valor = $row['valor'] eu pego a variavél dele e faço uma comparação, se o valor for 15 ele é trocado pelo 3, depois eu ainda salvo o valor em uma outra variel, eu coloco o valor em outra variavel por precaução não tem a necessidade, então vamos supor que temos um select com dois valores, temos os valores 15 e 16 nas options, mas o atributo que criamos tem os valores 3 e 4 ficaria assim:

**Exemplo**

```
 if ($valor == 15) {
     $valor = 3;         //TROCAR PELO VALUE NUMERO DA OPTION
     $valorx = $valor;
     } 
 if ($valor == 16) {
     $valor = 4;         //TROCAR PELO VALUE NUMERO DA OPTION
     $valorx = $valor;
     }
```

**Código**

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select)){
                            $teste = array(
                                    $clientes_id = $row['clientes_id'],
                                    $nome = $row['nome'],
                                    $sobrenome = $row['sobrenome'],
                                    $site = $row['site'],
                                    $loja = $row['loja'],
                                    $grupo = $row['grupo'],
                                    $prefixo = $row['prefixo'],
                                    $assinatura = $row['assinatura']);

                                    if ($loja == 15) {
                                    $loja = 3;         //TROCAR PELO VALUE NUMERO DA OPTION
                                    $lojax = $loja;
                                }  

    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
                                    $customer->setId($clientes_id)
                                             ->setFirstname($nome)
                                             ->setLastname($sobrenome)
                                             ->setWebsiteId($site)
                                             ->setStoreId($loja)
                                             ->setGroupId($grupo)
                                             ->setPrefix($prefixo)
                                             ->setMiddlename($assinatura);
```

Comment: Bem legal a forma como vc tá trabalhando com essa lógica ai, me fez lembrar quando eu modifiquei o admin do magento, criando uma extensão para trocar o banner e a logo, tive que fazer umas inserções no banco de dados tbem, pelo admin, mas é uma lógica quase parecida com essa, só que é toda no back-end mesmo

Comment: Sim, o magento é uma ferramenta complexa e simples ao mesmo tempo, só temos que "desvendar" ela e ela vira uma ótima ferramenta.